# How to correctly add biography for SVJour3 template?

Tags: sv-classes, biography

For IEEE template I added biography using the following snippet:

```
\begin{IEEEbiography}
...
\end{IEEEbiography}
```

How to add biography with SVJour3?

I have already checked https://latextemplates.github.io/svjour/

However, nothing is mentioned about how to add biography correctly with the SVJour3 template.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplified "paper" with a picture and a short text added at the end.

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass[twocolumn,natbib,english]{svjour3}        % twocolumn

\usepackage{graphicx}% added <<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{wrapfig}% added <<<<<<<<<<  

\begin{document}
        
\title{TITLE}

\author{First Author \and Second Author }

\institute{
  F.~Author\at
  University of Something \\
  \email{fauthor@example.org}
  \and
  S.~Author\at
  University of Anything \\
  \email{sauthor@example.org}
}

\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The text of the abstract.

\keywords{keyword1 \and keyword2}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
The remainder of the paper starts with a presentation of related work.
It is followed by a presentation of hints on \LaTeX{}.
Finally, a conclusion is drawn and outlook on future work is made.
    
\begin{acknowledgements}
  Winery is a graphical modeling tool.
The whole idea of TOSCA is explained.
\end{acknowledgements}

{\setlength\intextsep{0pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{25mm} 
    \includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}\par
\noindent\textbf{Springer Nature}\\ The company originates from a number of journals and publishing houses, notably Springer-Verlag, which was founded in 1842 by Julius Springer in Berlin (the grandfather of Bernhard Springer who founded Springer Publishing in 1950 in New York), Nature Publishing Group which publishes Nature since 1869, and Macmillan Education, which goes back to Macmillan Publishers founded in 1843.\par}

\end{document}
```

[image: b]

Comment: thanks for your response. But I am looking for biography not bibliography.

Comment: @Exploring Sorry for my confusion. I added a code to add an image and a short text.